# Error connecting to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com using mono and ubuntu

Tags: c#, ios, ssl, mono, push-notification

I'm trying to connect to apns and get the exception: invalid certificate received from server. A possible solution I found was disabling the validation, but it didnt't work:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
```

Other solution found was adding certificates to mono due to mono store is empty by default, 
but doesn't work either:

```
certmgr -ssl https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

Here is the code to connect:

```
 //load certificate
        var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2 ("cert.pem", "xxx");
        var clientCertificate2 = new X509Certificate2 ("entrust_ca.pem");
        var certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificatesCollection.Add (clientCertificate);
        certificatesCollection.Add (clientCertificate2);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

        var client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
        var sslStream = new SslStream (client.GetStream (), false);

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Default, false); //crash here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex);
            //client.Close();
            //return;
        }
```

Any ideas please